# Django inheritance obtain typeof child from base class

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have three models like following:

```
from model_utils.managers import InheritanceManager

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, verbose_name="Type here name",)

class Pub(Product):
    product = models.OneToOneField(Product, parent_link=True, )
    seating_capacity = models.IntegerField(null=False, verbose_name="Seating capacity of the Pub",)

class Restaurant(Product):
   product = models.OneToOneField(Product, parent_link=True, )
   food_speciality = MultiSelectField(choices = MY_CHOICES)
```

I have implemented django-cart and have attached Product as my product model. I return all the products to my frontend. This basically sends product objects with only product specific attributes to the frontend, and hence it is hard to distinguish which product is Pub and which one is Restaurant.

How can I handle this on backend itself? Is there any way to extract/send also the type of products?

This is how my view looks like:

```
@api_view(('GET',))
def show(request):
    cart = Cart(request.session)
    products = cart.products
    serializer = ProductSerializer(products, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

It returns for example:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Shreyas","price":"45000.00000","avg_user_rating":"4.50000","city":1},{"id":4,"name":"Phadake","price":"350.00000","avg_user_rating":"5.00000","city":2}]
```

Serializer:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    class Meta:
            model = Product
            fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**

Add the `Meta` class with `verbose_name` to you models:

```
class Pub(Product):
    product = models.OneToOneField(Product, parent_link=True, )
    seating_capacity = models.IntegerField(null=False, verbose_name="Seating capacity of the Pub",)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Pub'

class Restaurant(Product):
    product = models.OneToOneField(Product, parent_link=True, )
    food_speciality = MultiSelectField(choices = MY_CHOICES)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Restaurant'
```

Add these lines to `ProductSerializer`:

```
category = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

def get_category(self, obj):
    return obj._meta.verbose_name
```

**Option 2**

Alternatively, you can add a `property` to each model.

```
class Pub(Product):
    product = models.OneToOneField(Product, parent_link=True, )
    seating_capacity = models.IntegerField(null=False, verbose_name="Seating capacity of the Pub",)

    @property
    def category(self):
        return 'Pub'

class Restaurant(Product):
    product = models.OneToOneField(Product, parent_link=True, )
    food_speciality = MultiSelectField(choices = MY_CHOICES)

    @property
    def category(self):
        return 'Restaurant'
```

Then add this line to `ProductSerializer`:

```
category = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
```

**Option 3**

Of course, you also have the option do this if you don't want to add Meta or properties to your models:

```
def get_category(self, obj):
    return obj.__class__.__name__
```

But then you would have the restriction that every category would be equal to the class's name, which might be a problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try that.

Comment: I went with option 2 and updated my serializer, but it returned the same response. I have updated my question with serializer code. Can you please take a look?

Comment: Remove `fields = '__all__'` from your serializer's Meta. Did you remember to add a `category` property to each of your models?

Comment: Yes I added category to Pub and Rest. When I replace '__all__' with ['category'], it gives [{},{}]

Comment: I get what is happening. Your products seem to always be instances of `Product`  when you fetch them with `cart.products`. I see you instantiate a `Cart` object with your session data, probably from which products are instantiated. Make sure these products are being instantiated with the correct class. You can for example check `obj`'s class inside of your serializer's method. About `fields`, no need to define it at all, just remove it from Meta.

Comment: Yes I had to associate one model as my product to be inserted/deleted from my cart, and there I used Product model. Further I inherited from this Product to have Pub and Rest. I think it will always instantiate with Product. If I fetch only Pubs or Rests, it returns category with it.

Comment: Exactly. When you do `Pub.objects.filter(...)`, all objects will be `Pub` instances. Same applies to `Restaurant`. If you fetch products with `Product.objects.filter(...)`, or instantiate objects with `Product(**some_session_data)`, they will always be `Product` instances (thus won't have category) no matter what class they had when they were stored in the database.

Comment: They will if each product is instantiated correctly inside `Cart`, so that you have products with the correct classes in `cart.products`. You can probably do that based on what kind of info you have in each product that is in session.

Comment: So looks like I will have to modify Cart itself :(